# How to install npm in thimble

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, requirejs, npm

I try to install thimble following instructions [here](https://github.com/mozilla/thimble.webmaker.org). I successfully installed Bramble, but when I try to install npm in thimble, this error is showed:

```
C:\Users\Askar\Documents\GitHub> cd .\thimble.webmaker.org
C:\Users\Askar\Documents\GitHub\thimble.webmaker.org [bramble +1 ~0 -0 !]> npm install
|
> thimble@2.0.0 postinstall C:\Users\Askar\Documents\GitHub\thimble.webmaker.org

> bower install && node_modules/.bin/grunt requirejs:dist

'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! thimble@2.0.0 postinstall: `bower install && node_modules/.bin/grunt requirejs:dist`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the thimble@2.0.0 postinstall script 'bower install && node_modules/.bin/grunt requirejs:dist'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the thimble package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     bower install && node_modules/.bin/grunt requirejs:dist
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls thimble
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Askar\Documents\GitHub\thimble.webmaker.org\npm-debug.log
C:\Users\Askar\Documents\GitHub\thimble.webmaker.org [bramble +1 ~0 -0 !]>
```

How can I get through this error?

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with the `postInstall` scripts fail (at least on Windows) because the first command makes the script navigate to the folder where the `bower` command is run (cmd runs all the subsequential commands with the same path?). While that's being fixed, you run the commands yourself

```
npm install //this will fail
"node_modules/.bin/bower" install
"node_modules/.bin/grunt" requirejs:dist
```

or if you have installed `bower` and `grunt` globally (`npm install -g bower grunt-cli`), you can just do

```
bower install
grunt install
```

edit: this has now been fixed in the latest master